# Permission denied error on executing localstack init script file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

I am trying to create s3 bucket on localstack ready hook using a bash file. But on trying to run the localstack container getting error as follow:

[  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/buckets.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/buckets.sh'

The docker-compose volume section for localstack is as follow:

volumes:

```
  - ./internal/localstack-seed:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d
```

Answer (score 4):

please make sure the file is executable by running `chmod +x buckets.sh`, or you can cover the whole folder with `find /path/to/folder -type f -exec chmod +x {} \;`. this is mentioned in the [init hooks documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks/), but towards the end, which might make it less visible.

if you're using [localstack init hooks with frameworks like testcontainers](https://github.com/tinyg210/localstack-tc-init-hooks), you can explicitly set the mode of the file, or you need to watch out that the new permissions are being picked up.